# Converting CASE statements with subqueries that flatten data to SSIS

Tags: switch-statement, case, ssis

This week I took a SQL Statement with 11 case statements with sub query lookups and made 11 joins to a temp table I created at the beginning of this query, as a quick and dirty solution to get this file out in a short term solution, with the idea of this part of the query being to take rows and flatten them to columns in the output file. I would like to convert this query to an efficient SSIS package as there are additional "massaging" steps that are taking place manually that can be taken care of in the package.

What is the best way to work these CASE statements in to SSIS so that this will execute efficiently? I tried using the Temp table but had multiple issues with that and wasn't sure if that's the best solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information about the issue you are trying to solve all i can really say is that you can use the conditional data flow component to separate your rows and do some further treatment. However, this might not be the fastest option, depending on your additional "massaging" steps.